# "Land Baron"/"Master Architect" achievable over multiple playthroughs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements, skyrim-hearthfire

There are two vaguely worded achievements in the Skyrim Hearthfire expansion:

*Land Baron*:

> Buy three plots of land

*Master Architect*:

> Build three houses

Does this mean that all three plots of land must be bought in a single playthrough, and all three houses must be built in a single playthrough to earn the achievements? Or could I play through the game three times, each time buying one plot of land and building one house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achievements are baked into the saves themselves* -- the file containing your Level 2 Bosmer Thief doesn't know anything about your past life as a level 82 Nord "100-in-Everything". Which is to say, **no, you must achieve achievements in a single playthrough**.

*Incidentally, this is why it is possible to mod out the "Can't earn Achievements with Mods" feature of Skyrim SE.